# RxJava MultiThreading

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a question about RxJava in Android, I'm fairly new to the concept of RxJava and reactive programming. I was Thinking if there is a way that with RxJava in android we could like start a download in an activity with retrofit and RxJava, after the download started, for example, we get out of the activity or close it but we want still listen for the download to complete in some way. if anyone has any knowledge about this please share.

Comment: This is of course possible with RxJava, but you need to ask a specific question....

Comment: @Appyx and what do you mean by a specific question this question is bright as a day. I want to know how to handle other threads which are made by RxJava with RxJava.

Comment: Please show some code for what you have tried so far and than explain the problem you have. There is no point in answering this question because there are endless possibilities..

Comment: @AppyxI have tried nothing cause I don't have any idea from where to start and for that, I asked this question.

Comment: Ok, for that there are many blog posts out there. Tip: It's all about disposing the subscription.

Comment: @Appyx Thank you for your tip, I will search for it

Comment: @Appyx I have read about disposing but disposing is not what I'm looking for. I want my Disposable to be on call and I think my Observable must be a hot Observable. and it must be in another thread while downloading and when it finishes the download at all costs alert me in some way.

Comment: @Appyx oh now I get it you are saying I create an Observable which when the download is complete when it is getting disposed I call the methods which shows me the progress is over. That is a good idea. but what if I want to see the download progress in all of my activities. what solution do you have for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a JobIntentService(for Android Oreo compatibility) for the download which publishes the progress through a PublishSubject. Each Activity can subscribe to the service at some point in time.

The important thing is that the Activity disposes it's subscription when the app is going into background execution.
Disposing will not cancel the download and subscribing will not restart the download in this case because you are using a hot observable (the PublishSubject).

The progress is published onNext.
The completion onComplete.
Any errors onError.

For global access to the subject you could use a Singleton.

Another inportant thing is that each subscriber switches to the MainThread (by using the observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread) function before subscribing) so that you can modify the UI.

Have fun :)

Comment: I was reading about JobIntentServices. I was thinking about it why even should I use JobIntentServces to start the download instead of using PublishSubject on Schedulers.newThread(). is there a benefit in it?

Comment: It's about background execution of your app.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Yes i got it but i don't need to run it in background

Comment: Then you don't need an IntentService. But you need something that holds a reference to your Subject like a singleton.